# Privacy policy generator

Tags: wordpress, web, plugins, privacy-policy

I want to create a privacy policy generator with wordpress. That is, a function on your future site where the user could create it for himself. Maybe one of you knows which plugin is better to use?

I wanted to create something like this https://app.freeprivacypolicy.com/wizard/privacy-policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress already includes the option to create a Privacy Policy right from Settings > Privacy.

[image]